# How to start stop azure container instance using Powershell command or ARM command

Tags: azure, containers, instance

I know you can start / stop container instance from Azure CLI using below command 
az container stop --name mycontainer --resource-group myResourceGroupVM

but since in my org azure cli gives "Access is denied" error i want to know how to do same using powershell or ARM. I am unable to get any powershell cmdlet to start or stop conrainer instance from documentation. Please help.

I referred below documentation for same:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.containerinstance/?view=azurermps-6.9.0#container_instances

Also could anyone tell me why I get "Access is denied." for all az (CLI ) commands?

Comment: If the answer helps you solve the issue you can accept it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the PowerShell cmdlet to stop the ACI and the cmdlet will like this:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName yourResourceGroup -ResourceName yourContainerGroup -Action Stop -ResourceType Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

The result of the PowerShell cmdlet like this:

[image]

Also, it shows the state on the Azure Portal:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To perform this action using the newer Powershell 'Az' modules:

```
$cg = Get-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName <yourResourceGroupName> -Name <yourContainerGroupName>

Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceId $cg.Id -Action start -Force
```

The `Action` parameter can be `start`, `stop`, `restart`.

I got those possible values from the Azure Resource Explorer: https://resources.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/operations

Answer (score 0):

You can do `Start-AzContainerGroup` now.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.containerinstance/start-azcontainergroup?view=azps-9.6.0)'s the documentation.