# Azure function app with powershell cannot start container instances

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-container-instances

There is a resource group with two important resource types: first one is a Container Instances (Linux). Second one is a Function App (Powershell, Windows). A function from the latter should start the former but it throws an error: *Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null*

What do I miss? The answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592629/how-to-start-stop-azure-container-instance-using-powershell-command-or-arm-comma) gives the same error only when running within Function App, in Azure or in VSCode with Function Tools. When run in a terminal, the command `Invoke-AzResourceAction` works as it should.

Here is the function code:

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Timer)

# Get the current universal time in the default string format
$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

# The 'IsPastDue' porperty is 'true' when the current function invocation is later than scheduled.
if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
}

# Write an information log with the current time.
Write-Host "PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: $currentUTCtime"

$cg = Get-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName some-group-name -Name container-instance-name

Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceId $cg.Id `
    -Action start `
    -Force
```

Here is the output log:

> Executing task: func host start
>
> Azure Functions Core Tools Core Tools Version:       3.0.2996 Commit
> hash: c54cdc36323e9543ba11fb61dd107616e9022bba Function Runtime
> Version: 3.0.14916.0
>
> Functions:
>
> (function name): timerTrigger
>
> For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag. Executing
> 'Functions.' (Reason='Timer fired at
> 2020-12-04T13:11:01.1496065+02:00',
> Id=c0b30df8-065d-4725-8fa7-22fdfad71a21) Trigger Details:
> UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule:
> 2020-12-04T13:11:00.0000000+02:00 Worker process started and
> initialized. INFORMATION: PowerShell timer is running late!
> INFORMATION: PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: 12/04/2020
> 11:11:06 INFORMATION:
> /subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/
> ERROR: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is
> null.
>
> Exception             :
> Type              : System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException
> Message           : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
> ParameterName     : InputObject
> ParameterType     : System.Object
> ErrorId           : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed
> CommandInvocation :
> MyCommand        : Trace-PipelineObject
> HistoryId        : 1
> InvocationName   : Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker\Trace-PipelineObject
> PipelineLength   : 2
> PipelinePosition : 2
> ExpectingInput   : True
> ErrorRecord       :
> Exception             :
> Type    : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> Message : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
> HResult : -2146233087
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Trace-PipelineObject], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Commands.TracePipelineObjectCommand
> InvocationInfo        :
> MyCommand       : Trace-PipelineObject
> HistoryId       : 1
> CommandOrigin   : Internal
> ScriptStackTrace      : at , \orchestration<function name>\run.ps1: line 19
> TargetSite        :
> Name          : BindValueFromPipeline
> DeclaringType : System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController,
> System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
> MemberType    : Method
> Module        : System.Management.Automation.dll
> StackTrace        :     at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindValueFromPipeline(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn, MergedCompiledCommandParameter parameter,
> ParameterBindingFlags flags)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindUnboundParametersForBindingStateInParameterSet(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn, CurrentlyBinding currentlyBinding, UInt32
> validParameterSets)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindUnboundParametersForBindingState(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn, CurrentlyBinding currentlyBinding, UInt32
> validParameterSets)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindPipelineParametersPrivate(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindPipelineParameters(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.Read()
> Source            : System.Management.Automation
> HResult           : -2146233087 CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Trace-PipelineObject],
> ParameterBindingValidationException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Commands.TracePipelineObjectCommand
> InvocationInfo        :
> MyCommand       : Trace-PipelineObject
> HistoryId       : 1
> CommandOrigin   : Internal ScriptStackTrace      : at , \orchestration<function name>\run.ps1:
> line 19
>
> Result: ERROR: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because
> it is null.
>
> Exception             :
> Type              : System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException
> Message           : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
> ParameterName     : InputObject
> ParameterType     : System.Object
> ErrorId           : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed
> CommandInvocation :
> MyCommand        : Trace-PipelineObject
> HistoryId        : 1
> InvocationName   : Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker\Trace-PipelineObject
> PipelineLength   : 2
> PipelinePosition : 2
> ExpectingInput   : True
> ErrorRecord       :
> Exception             :
> Type    : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> Message : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
> HResult : -2146233087
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Trace-PipelineObject], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Commands.TracePipelineObjectCommand
> InvocationInfo        :
> MyCommand       : Trace-PipelineObject
> HistoryId       : 1
> CommandOrigin   : Internal
> ScriptStackTrace      : at , <function name>\run.ps1: line 19
> TargetSite        :
> Name          : BindValueFromPipeline
> DeclaringType : System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController,
> System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
> MemberType    : Method
> Module        : System.Management.Automation.dll
> StackTrace        :    at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindValueFromPipeline(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn, MergedCompiledCommandParameter parameter,
> ParameterBindingFlags flags)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindUnboundParametersForBindingStateInParameterSet(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn, CurrentlyBinding currentlyBinding, UInt32
> validParameterSets)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindUnboundParametersForBindingState(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn, CurrentlyBinding currentlyBinding, UInt32
> validParameterSets)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindPipelineParametersPrivate(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindPipelineParameters(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn)          at
> System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.Read()
> Source            : System.Management.Automation
> HResult           : -2146233087 CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Trace-PipelineObject],
> ParameterBindingValidationException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Commands.TracePipelineObjectCommand
> InvocationInfo        :
> MyCommand       : Trace-PipelineObject
> HistoryId       : 1
> CommandOrigin   : Internal ScriptStackTrace      : at , \orchestration<function name>\run.ps1:
> line 19 Exception: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject'
> because it is null. Stack:    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindValueFromPipeline(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn, MergedCompiledCommandParameter parameter,
> ParameterBindingFlags flags)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindUnboundParametersForBindingStateInParameterSet(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn, CurrentlyBinding currentlyBinding, UInt32
> validParameterSets)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindUnboundParametersForBindingState(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn, CurrentlyBinding currentlyBinding, UInt32
> validParameterSets)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindPipelineParametersPrivate(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn)    at
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindPipelineParameters(PSObject
> inputToOperateOn)          at
> System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.Read(). Executed
> 'Functions.' (Succeeded,
> Id=c0b30df8-065d-4725-8fa7-22fdfad71a21, Duration=13327ms) Host lock
> lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000008ABBCF1E'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, one of the commands in your script outputs $null, which hits this bug: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/561. Most likely, `Invoke-AzResourceAction` does that. The workaround is to redirect or capture the output, for example:

```
Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceId $cg.Id `
    -Action start `
    -Force | Out-Null
```

The bug has been recently fixed, but it will take a few weeks for the fix to be deployed to Azure.